# strategy for corect naming 2 urns based on drawing 2 balls from a randomly chosen urn

Tags: probability

I am analyzing the below problem from the book "Fifty challenging problems in probability" by Mosteller.
I don't understand how the the proposed solution was deduced.

> Two urns contain red and black balls, all alike except for color Urn A
>   has 2  reds and 1 black, and Urn B has 101 reds and 100 blacks. An urn
>   is chosen at  random, and you win a prize if you correctly name the
>   urn on the basis of the  evidence of two bails drawn from it. After
>   the first ball is drawn and its color  reported, you can decide
>   whether or not the ball shall be replaced before the  second drawing.
>   How do you order the second drawing, and how do you  decide on the urn
>   ?

The solution suggests that if the first ball is red it should be replaced and if it is black it shouldn't.
Giving the probabilities of each combination of balls for each urns as follows


**Strategy 1: if red first replace, if black first don't replace** 
**Urn A** 
$$
P(A \ RR)= \frac{16}{72} \quad \quad \quad
P(A \ RB)= \frac{8}{72} \quad \quad \quad
P(A \ BR)= \frac{12}{72} \quad \quad \quad
P(A \ BB)= 0 \quad \quad \quad
$$
**Urn B** 
$$
P(B \ RR) \approx \frac{1}{8}=\frac{9}{72} \quad 
P(B \ RB) \approx \frac{1}{8}=\frac{9}{72} \quad 
P(B \ BR) \approx \frac{1}{8}=\frac{9}{72} \quad 
P(B \ BB) \approx \frac{1}{8}=\frac{9}{72} \quad $$

where for example P(A RB) denotes probability of drawing red and then black from the urn A and is calculated as $\frac{1}{2} \frac{2}{3} \frac{1}{3}$  
and P(B RB) as $\frac{1}{2} \frac{101}{201} \frac{100}{201} \approx \frac{1}{8}$

The toatl probability of naming correctly the urn is calculated as
$$\frac{1}{2} \Big{[} \frac{4}{9} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \Big{]} \approx \frac{23}{36} = 0.64$$

**I don't understand why just this strategy is chosen and what is the logic of the calculation for the total probability of the correctly naming the urn?**

It seems that any other strategy could work in similar way (2. no replacement both, 3. no repl. red, replacement black, 4. replacement both) where knowing the result of the drawing gives the corresponding probabilities for the urn A and B. How it can be proved that the strategy 1. is better?

**There are my calculations for the other strategies**

 



**Strategy 2: no replacements** 
**Urn A** 
$$
P(A \ RR)= \frac{12}{72} \quad \quad \quad
P(A \ RB)= \frac{12}{72} \quad \quad \quad
P(A \ BR)= \frac{12}{72} \quad \quad \quad
P(A \ BB)= 0  \quad \quad \quad
$$
**Urn B** 
$$
P(B \ RR) \approx \frac{9}{72} \quad \quad \quad 
P(B \ RB) \approx \frac{9}{72} \quad \quad \quad 
P(B \ BR) \approx \frac{9}{72} \quad \quad \quad 
P(B \ BB) \approx \frac{9}{72} \quad \quad \quad $$

**Strategy 3 : red no replacement , black replacement** 
**Urn A** 
$$
P(A \ RR)= \frac{16}{72} \quad \quad \quad
P(A \ RB)= \frac{6}{72} \quad \quad \quad
P(A \ BR)= \frac{8}{72} \quad \quad \quad
P(A \ BB)= \frac{4}{72} \quad \quad \quad
$$
**Urn B** 
$$
P(B \ RR) \approx \frac{9}{72} \quad \quad \quad 
P(B \ RB) \approx \frac{9}{72} \quad \quad \quad 
P(B \ BR) \approx \frac{9}{72} \quad \quad \quad 
P(B \ BB) \approx \frac{9}{72} \quad \quad \quad $$

**Strategy 4: replace in either case red or black** 
**Urn A** 
$$
P(A \ RR)= \frac{16}{72} \quad \quad \quad
P(A \ RB)= \frac{8}{72} \quad \quad \quad
P(A \ BR)= \frac{8}{72} \quad \quad \quad
P(A \ BB)= \frac{4}{72} \quad \quad \quad
$$
**Urn B** 
$$
P(B \ RR) \approx \frac{9}{72} \quad \quad \quad 
P(B \ RB) \approx \frac{9}{72} \quad \quad \quad 
P(B \ BR) \approx \frac{9}{72} \quad \quad \quad 
P(B \ BB) \approx \frac{9}{72} \quad \quad \quad $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decide for each outcome the urn with highest probability.

For strategy 1:

If you get $RR$, you should decide $A$ since $P(A\ RR)>P(B\ RR)$

If you get $RB$, you should decide $B$, since $P(A\ RB)<P(B\ RB)$

If you get $BR$, you should decide $A$ since $P(A\ BR)>P(B\ BR)$

If you get $BB$, you should decide $B$, since $P(A\ BB)<P(B\ BB)$

$$P(\text{correct decision})= P(A\ RR)+P(B\ RB)+P(A\ BR)+P(B\ BB)\\
\approx\frac{16}{72}+\frac{9}{72}+\frac{12}{72}+\frac{9}{72}=\frac{45}{72}\approx 0.64$$

For the other strategies, you do the same way. Assuming that your calculations are correct:

Strategy 2:
$$P(\text{correct decision})= P(A\ RR)+P(A\ RB)+P(A\ BR)+P(B\ BB)\\
\approx\frac{12}{72}+\frac{12}{72}+\frac{12}{72}+\frac{9}{72}=\frac{46}{72}\approx 0.625$$

Strategy 3:
$$P(\text{correct decision})= P(A\ RR)+P(B\ RB)+P(B\ BR)+P(B\ BB)\\
\approx\frac{16}{72}+\frac{9}{72}+\frac{9}{72}+\frac{9}{72}=\frac{43}{72}\approx 0.60$$

Strategy 4:
$$P(\text{correct decision})= P(A\ RR)+P(B\ RB)+P(B\ BR)+P(B\ BB)\\
\approx\frac{16}{72}+\frac{9}{72}+\frac{9}{72}+\frac{9}{72}=\frac{43}{72}\approx 0.60$$

The best strategy is the one with the highest probability of correct decision (which is strategy 1).

The intuitive explanation is that you have to "imbalance" the percentage of red vs black balls in the two urns as much as possible, in order to maximize your chance to discriminate between the two urns at the next drawing.

If you get a red ball from the first urn and you don't put it back, you will have 1 red / 1 black in the first urn and 101 reds /100 blacks in the second urn. it would be very hard to distinguish at the second drawing whether the balls came from the first or the second urn, since both urns have probability of a red ball of about 50% now. So it is better to put the red ball back in order to maintain the imbalance.

If you get the black ball from the first urn and you don't put it back, you are guaranteed to get a red ball at the next drawing. So there will be strong evidence that you are extracting from the first urn (100% vs about 50%). If you put the black ball back, the imbalance would be only of 60% vs about 50%, so it will be harder to distinguish. So you should not replace the black ball.

For the second urn, it doesn't matter that much whether you keep the ball or put it back (the probabilities change much less so it will not be that much of a difference). So the decision should be taken in accordance to the first urn.

Comment: @ Momo How can it be proved numerically that the strategy number 1 is superior? What is the probability 0.64 representing, what is the logic behind?

Comment: @Michal I added more details with how the probability of correct decision is calculated for the first strategy. Hope it helps.